# How to convert a column of dates as text to Excel dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on a spreadsheet and imported external information with a date format of yyyy mm dd.  I understand excel recognizes this as text as it's left aligned, however I need to convert this into a date format excel recognizes for other formulas I have built in.  I've been googling for hours and am growing very frustrated.  Also, these dates are in column H2:H207.  There has to be a simpler way to convert other than "hand jamming" everything in.  All help is appreciated!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/241289/dates-not-recognized-as-dates-in-pivot-table-pulling-directly-from-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Use that:

```
=DATE(LEFT(H2;4);MID(H2;6;2);RIGHT(H2;2))
```

If all dates are exactly in `yyyy mm dd` format, it should work.

I use this trick quite often. It gets year, month and day numbers from a text string with LEFT, MID and RIGHT functions and put it together into proper date using DATE function. It might be slightly modified if formatting is not exactly like you've said or if it's not "clear" and dates' elements need to be found with a bit more "flexible" method.

Comment: Appreciate it.  Although I haven't tried this way I tried what seems like a simpler way.  First I highlighted the column, clicked on menu tab Data, then Text to Columns.  Selected "Fixed width", deleted both black lines separating the text data, clicked next.  Selected Date: and made sure format was YMD and clicked finish!  All of it was done.

Comment: Well, not sure if this solution sounds simpler, however - whatever works! ;)